# Seating four girls and two boys in a row such that the boys do not sit together

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

If $2$ boys are never to sit together and $4$ girls and $2$ boys are to sit in linear line.? Then total number of such arrangements is:

My solution:

The total number of linear arrangements is $6!$ and the number of arrangements when $2$ boys are to sit together is $5!$ so the answer should be $6!-5!=600$. Am I right here?

Comment: I think answer is $6!-2.5!$ as two boys can sit in a two different way.

Comment: you should multiply by two because boy 1 boy 2 and boy 2 boy 1 are the same arrangement.

Comment: Your title does not match your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is $6!-2.5!$ as two boy can sit together in a two different way.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my addition of the word "together". $(+1)$, BTW

Comment: @amWhy: it seems better :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider $2$ boys as a single unit.

Then possible ways of arranging boys & $4$ girls = arrangements such  that $2 $ boys sit together  => $5!=120$

Now , since $2$ boys are never to sit together ,
the number of required arrangements  => $$6! -(2\times120)$$
$$=720-240$$
$$=480$$

Comment: "arrangements such that 2 boys sit together" is $2\times 5! = 240.$ In your effort to correct your incorrect post (given @mesel's correct post), you forgot to correct your first sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you have four "girls-only" seats :
$$ \sqcup \quad \sqcup \quad \sqcup \quad \sqcup$$
and you want to insert two "boys-only" seats, but not side-by-side, that is among the points in :
$$ \cdot \sqcup \cdot \sqcup \cdot \sqcup \cdot \sqcup \cdot$$

Then you need to choose $2$ spots among the $5$ dots : there is $\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\end{pmatrix}$ such possibilities.

Now choose one of those possibilities : to seat the four girls on the "girls-only" seats, you have $4!$ ways of doing it ; for each of those ways, you need to put the boys in the "boys-only" seats, for which there is $2$ ways. So for each seats order, you have $2 \times 4!$ ways of putting the girls and boys in the seats.

At the end, you have $2 \times 4! \times\begin{pmatrix}5\\2\end{pmatrix} = 4! \times 20$ possible arrangements.

Answer (score 1):

Considering only 'boy' $\textbf{b}$ and 'girl' $\textbf{g}$ we only have

$$
\frac{6!}{2!4!} = 15
$$

permutations, they are given by

$$
\textbf{bbgggg} - \textbf{bgbggg} - \textbf{bggbgg} - \textbf{bgggbg} - \textbf{bggggb}\\
\textbf{gbbggg} - \textbf{gbgbgg} - \textbf{gbggbg} - \textbf{gbgggb}\\
\textbf{ggbbgg} - \textbf{ggbgbg} - \textbf{ggbggb}\\
\textbf{gggbbg} - \textbf{gggbgb}\\
\textbf{ggggbb}\\
$$

The condition that two boys never sit together means to exclude permutation containing 
$$
\textbf{bb}
$$

That are $5$ permutations, so we obtain

$$
16 - 5 = 10
$$

permutations, they are given by

$$
\textbf{bgbggg} - \textbf{bggbgg} - \textbf{bgggbg} - \textbf{bggggb}\\
\textbf{gbgbgg} - \textbf{gbggbg} - \textbf{gbgggb}\\
\textbf{ggbgbg} - \textbf{ggbggb}\\
\textbf{gggbgb}\\
$$

The general case is given by

$$
\frac{\big(b+g\big)!}{b!g!} - g - 1
$$

---

If we label the 'boys' and 'girls' we need to multiply by

$$
b!g!
$$

so we get

$$
\big(b+g\big)! - b!\big(g+1\big)!
$$

As in this case we get

$$
6! - 2! 5! = 480
$$